# jQuery clipping mask?

Tags: jquery, mask

What's the best jQuery plugin (or any other javascript method) that allows me to create a clipping mask of a div.

Let's say I have a mask (a triangle) and an image. How can I only show a triangular part of the image using my mask?

I don't want to use to images, eg: 1 picture with the image, over which I put another absolute positioned div (transparent .png) with a triangle hole in it.

Soooooo???.... :D

Comment: Not an answer, but just an FYI, the CSS clip property only supports one shape; rect.

Comment: Sure, anything: CSS,jQuery,HTML5,CSS3, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're open to html5, then look at the canvas element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing

Comment: Does this work only on mozilla? I'm looking for a cross-browser solution

Comment: There's a library (excanvas => http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) that draws canvas on supported browsers and VML on IE, wrapping different calls within an unified API

Comment: @Cristy - you said html5 was ok. That implies that you're not looking cross-browser! The library from @steweb is interesting, however.

Comment: broken link is broken

Answer (score 0):

If its just an image you want to mask, you could use the [RaphaelJs](http://raphaeljs.com/) library which is cross-browser and even works in IE6. Basically you draw a shape and fill it with your image:

```
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("notepad"), 400, 400);
var r = paper.g.triangle(200, 200, 190);

r.attr({
    stroke: "none",
    fill: "url(http://www.bing.com/fd/hpk2/NabobPass_EN-US1703601557.jpg)" 
});
```

Live demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/eybNG/

Note that  in my example I'm using the extra library [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/basic.html) which makes it very easy to draw a triangle. This is not required though.